# Python Naive Bayes with cross validation using GaussianNB classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to apply Naive Bayes with 10-fold stratified cross-validation to my data, and then I want to see how the model performs on the test data I set aside initially. 
However, the results I am getting (i.e. the predicted outcome and probability values `y_pred_nb2` and `y_score_nb2`) are identical to when I run the code without any cross-validation. 
QUESTION: How can I correct this?

The code is below, where `X_train` consists of 75% of the entire dataset and `X_test` consists of 25%.

```python
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 

params = {}

#gridsearch searches for the best hyperparameters and keeps the classifier with the highest recall score
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)

nb2 = GridSearchCV(GaussianNB(), cv=skf, param_grid=params)
%time nb2.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict values on the test set
y_pred_nb2 = nb2.predict(X_test) 

print(y_pred_nb2)

# predicted probabilities on the test set
y_scores_nb2 = nb2.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

print(y_scores_nb2)
```

Answer (score 4):

First off [`GaussianNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) only accepts `priors` as an argument so unless you have some priors to set for your model ahead of time you will have nothing to grid search over.

Furthermore, your `param_grid` is set to an empty dictionary which ensures that you only fit one estimator with `GridSearchCV`. This is the same as fitting an estimator without using a grid search (e.g., I use `MultinomialNB` in order to show use of hyperparameters):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
params = {}
nb = MultinomialNB()
gs = GridSearchCV(nb, cv=skf, param_grid=params, return_train_score=True)

data = load_iris()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target)

gs.fit(x_train, y_train)

gs.cv_results_
{'mean_fit_time': array([0.]),
 'mean_score_time': array([0.]),
 'mean_test_score': array([0.85714286]),
 'mean_train_score': array([0.85992157]),
 'params': [{}],
 'rank_test_score': array([1]),
 'split0_test_score': array([0.91666667]),
 'split0_train_score': array([0.84]),
 'split1_test_score': array([0.75]),
 'split1_train_score': array([0.86]),
 'split2_test_score': array([0.83333333]),
 'split2_train_score': array([0.84]),
 'split3_test_score': array([0.91666667]),
 'split3_train_score': array([0.83]),
 'split4_test_score': array([0.83333333]),
 'split4_train_score': array([0.85]),
 'split5_test_score': array([0.91666667]),
 'split5_train_score': array([0.84]),
 'split6_test_score': array([0.9]),
 'split6_train_score': array([0.88235294]),
 'split7_test_score': array([0.8]),
 'split7_train_score': array([0.88235294]),
 'split8_test_score': array([0.8]),
 'split8_train_score': array([0.89215686]),
 'split9_test_score': array([0.9]),
 'split9_train_score': array([0.88235294]),
 'std_fit_time': array([0.]),
 'std_score_time': array([0.]),
 'std_test_score': array([0.05832118]),
 'std_train_score': array([0.02175538])}

nb.fit(x_train, y_train)
nb.score(x_test, y_test)
0.8157894736842105

gs.score(x_test, y_test)
0.8157894736842105

gs.param_grid = {'alpha': [0.1, 2]}
gs.fit(x_train, y_train)
gs.score(x_test, y_test)
0.8421052631578947

gs.cv_results_
{'mean_fit_time': array([0.00090394, 0.00049713]),
 'mean_score_time': array([0.00029924, 0.0003005 ]),
 'mean_test_score': array([0.86607143, 0.85714286]),
 'mean_train_score': array([0.86092157, 0.85494118]),
 'param_alpha': masked_array(data=[0.1, 2],
              mask=[False, False],
        fill_value='?',
             dtype=object),
 'params': [{'alpha': 0.1}, {'alpha': 2}],
 'rank_test_score': array([1, 2]),
 'split0_test_score': array([0.91666667, 0.91666667]),
 'split0_train_score': array([0.84, 0.83]),
 'split1_test_score': array([0.75, 0.75]),
 'split1_train_score': array([0.86, 0.86]),
 'split2_test_score': array([0.83333333, 0.83333333]),
 'split2_train_score': array([0.85, 0.84]),
 'split3_test_score': array([0.91666667, 0.91666667]),
 'split3_train_score': array([0.83, 0.81]),
 'split4_test_score': array([0.83333333, 0.83333333]),
 'split4_train_score': array([0.85, 0.84]),
 'split5_test_score': array([0.91666667, 0.91666667]),
 'split5_train_score': array([0.84, 0.84]),
 'split6_test_score': array([0.9, 0.9]),
 'split6_train_score': array([0.88235294, 0.88235294]),
 'split7_test_score': array([0.9, 0.8]),
 'split7_train_score': array([0.88235294, 0.88235294]),
 'split8_test_score': array([0.8, 0.8]),
 'split8_train_score': array([0.89215686, 0.89215686]),
 'split9_test_score': array([0.9, 0.9]),
 'split9_train_score': array([0.88235294, 0.87254902]),
 'std_fit_time': array([0.00030147, 0.00049713]),
 'std_score_time': array([0.00045711, 0.00045921]),
 'std_test_score': array([0.05651628, 0.05832118]),
 'std_train_score': array([0.02103457, 0.02556351])}
```

Comment: Thanks @Grr So how do i run stratified 10-cross-fold validation on a Naive Bayes model in Python?

Comment: @KrishnaPatel the code I included utilizes a grid search with 10 fold stratified cross validation. Perhaps you are confused about cross validation? The point of cross validation isn't to build multiple estimators and get the most accurate one. The point of cross validation is to build an estimator against different cross sections of your data to gain an aggregate understanding of performance across all sections. This way you can avoid choosing a model based on a potentially biased split. See [sklearn's cross validation module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

#because only var_smoothing can be 'tuned'
#do a cross validation on different var_smoothing values

def cross_val(params):
    model = GaussianNB()
    model.set_params(**params)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train,
                             cv = 10, #10 folds
                             scoring = "accuracy",
                             verbose = 2
                            )
    #return the mean of the 10 fold cross validation
    return cv_results.mean()

#baseline parameters
params = {
          "priors" : "None",
          "var_smoothing" : 1e-9
}
#create an list of var_smoothing to cross validate
steps = [1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4]

#will contain the cv results
results = []
for step in steps:        
    params["var_smoothing"] = step        
    cv_result = cross_val(params)

    #save result
    results.append(cv_result)

#print results
#convert results to pandas dataframe for easier visualization
df = pd.DataFrame({"var_smoothing" : steps, "accuracy" : results})
#sort it
df_sorted = df.sort_values("accuracy", ascending=False)
#reset the index of the sorted dataframe
df_sorted.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_sorted.head()
```